# Application of integral

Tags: integration

[image]
 I solved the question this way $x=\sqrt{8y}$; $x=y^2$ and then I found the definite integral from $1$ to $3/2$ of $(\sqrt{8y}-y^2)$ but answer is different from my book is there any problem with my solution?

Comment: you approach is fine, check your calculations

Comment: Aren't the bounds $1$ and $3/2$ for $x$? For $y$ isn't $3/2$ accurate, the domain bounded by the two curves is between $y=0$ and $y=√2.$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $1$ and $3/2$ are the bounds when integrating wrt. $x$

$$\begin{aligned}\text{Area }&=\int_{1}^{3/2}\left(\sqrt{x}-\dfrac{1}{8}x^2\right)\mathrm dx\\&=\left[\dfrac{2}{3}x^{3/2}-\dfrac{1}{24}x^3\right]_{1}^{3/2}\approx0.459119871391589\end{aligned}$$